# How to retrieve value from assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a code like shown below
Here '`xmlSerializableType.AssemblyName`' value in this method coming as `"_Rounded_TreeGOLD, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"` which is the assembly name of user defined class and '`xmlSerializableType.Name`' as "_Rounded_Tree" .  Here i need to assign '`xmlSerializableType.Name`' to '`type`' something like `"GetType(xmlSerializableType.Name);"` so that 'type' becomes type = {Name = "_Rounded_Tree" FullName = "_Rounded_Tree"} How to acheive this, i mean What code i need to implement for "type"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `assembly = new Assembly()` you should load the assembly where the Type is located by using [`Assembly.Load("TheLongNameOfYourAssembly")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx)

Then on the loaded assembly you can do a GetType

Answer (score 0):

Like Wouter said, use Assembly.Load("AssemblyLongName").
On that assembly you can use assembly.GetTypes() or, even better assembly.GetExportedTypes() for "public" types only.

Iterate over the Types and check their names.
If you have some common base class or some more information you can check the various methods on [System.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type_methods.aspx)
For instance, you could use asmType.BaseType == typeof(yourBaseType) or
typeof(yourBaseType).IsAssignableFrom(asmType).

Have a look at the MSDN link, im pretty sure you will find everything needed there.

If you do know the exact Name assembly.GetType("yourExactTypeName") should work, too.

Comment: The problem for Assembly.Load is it will trigger a event handler 'Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)' this event handler code i have updated in my question just now. There 'classes' are not loading due to the nonloading of 'DataModelObjects'. This will happen some where during the loading of application, but with in that itself it will return null and will trigger exception like that assembly is not exiting even though it exists

Comment: you could just load the additional assemblies in your resolve-hander.
If there is something preventing that, i didn´t get it.
You could use Assembly.LoadFrom or Assembly.LoadFile in that event-handler.
But if you load the first assembly in the current (read default) appdomain, the assemblies should already be loaded i guess. This is hard to tell without knowing more of your application.

Comment: Have you tried setting the PrivateBinPath ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.privatebinpath.aspx ) for your AppDomain? Are you using different AppDomains?

Comment: I would recommend reading about AppDomains and making yourself a simple sample-application. Try this as a starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx
There are some links to How-Tos in that article.

Comment: See my assembly is creating without any issues,so no need to look on Appdomain, the problem is while loading my application, if i use 'Assembly.Load' it will trigger 'AssemblyResolve' event handler  which will return "null" value due to nonloading of 'classes' , hence 'DataModelObjects' these all are i mentioned in my question. Thats why i need an alternate way for getting value from 'xmlSerializableType.Name' to 'type'

Comment: When i debug my application i can see value for 'xmlSerializableType.Name' which is "_Rounded_Tree " so for successful operation i need to get 'type' as {Name = "_Rounded_Tree" FullName = "_Rounded_Tree"} , will i get it by doing some other coding rather than using 'Assembly.Load'

Comment: if the dependant assemblies can´t be loaded, i think there is no way to get the type out of that assembly. where is the assembly where these "DataModelObjects" are defined? Can't you load that assembly in the assemblyresolve-handler?